# How can I integrate mailchimp newsletter subscription in magento

Tags: mailchimp

I want to create a newsletter subscription which can be integrated with mailchimp.

I have a list in mailchimp and my site have four stores when any customer subscribe from any store its store name should be also added in store id in mail chimp account with all its subscription dtails.

Answer (score 0):

There is a freely available extension by ebizmarts and approved by Mailchimp for integration with Magento:

https://connect.mailchimp.com/integrations/magento

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-magemonkey-official-mailchimp-and-mandrill-extension.html